# Variable width bar of images

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox, css-grid

Good Evening,

I'm trying to create a 'bar' of images across my website which has variable width (upto 1024px). Rather than stretching the images, I want to keep a constant height and add or remove images to the bar depending on the website width.

As a starting point, assume all of the images are of the same dimension.

I'm considered using both grid and flexbox, but can't figure out where to start with either. I've done some searching, but can't find any examples to use as a basis.

I would rather avoid using `@media` queries if I can.

Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: It would help if you could provide a sketch or mockup of your idea.

Comment: I use flexbox on my  [gallery](http://sweaverd.com/gallery), not sure if this is your scenario exactly but have at it

Comment: @Sotkra good call - done

Comment: Since you use images fixed height, then put them inside the container with width 100%, height same as images and overflow hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update: having seen your sketch/mockup, I now understand what you're after.

Even though you want to avoid using media queries, it would be the best solution.

The general logic would be to determine the 'base' size of your images, let's say, 100px by 100px.

Then, based on the viewport width, and using media queries, you'd determine how many images you want to show at any given moment.

You must take into consideration that, viewport widths vary a lot, and you'll always have a partial division of total space / image size. You then have to decide what you want to do in such a case, normally, you define a fixed number of images per row and hide the rest.

Is this more or less what you're after?

Alternatively, as cjc pointed out, you'd make it so that images on the sides would hide if space isn't enough for them to show...but you'd still have partials unless you use flex-wrap, and then if that happens, you'd have empty space...so it all brings us back to queries :)

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I'm after. On reflection, I may have to go with media queries. I was hoping there would be an elegant solution using grid or flex box, but unfortunately not. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

At the most basic, you could simply hide all of the images that aren't shown like this:

```css
.photo-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px; /* I deliberately set the size smaller than the image height to show that it works with different image sizes. If all of the images are actually the same height then you probably want it to match the image height */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.photo-bar img {
  height: 100%;
  
  /* This is to make sure you don't introduce spaces between the pictures */
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='photo-bar'>
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
</div>
```

You could certainly get fancier using `flex-direction: row` although this it will be more complicated to get the described behavior (only showing the images that will fit). If you want a gallery that has a horizontal scrollbar, this is a better option.

```css
.photo-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.photo-bar img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='photo-bar'>
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/160x120' />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. A relatively simple solution. My guess is that all of the images will be downloaded though? I'm looking to only download the images that are required.

Comment: Yes, all of the images will be downloaded. If you want to only download the images that will be displayed and you don't want to use a media query, you'll need to use Javascript to insert the appropriate number of images for the size of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a starting place.

Did you also want the row of images centered?

---

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.image-bar {
    display: flex;
    
    /* no-wrap prevents the images from soft wrapping. */
    wrap: no-wrap;
    
    /* This will hide any images that are off the page. 
       I guess it wouldn't matter too much since you can't see
       the images anyways. */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-bar">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/150">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/150">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/150">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/150">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/150">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/150">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/150">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm unsure why you went to the effort of using javascript? Surely the more simple version of your answer is just to paste the images in as individual `<img>` tags? What is the benefit that you think this gives?

Comment: This could be modified so that the loop adds the appropriate number of images for the width of the page so that only the images that will be shown will be downloaded. The downside to that is that the images will load after the rest of the page.

Comment: @Jamie Yup, the Javascript was unnecessary. I just didn't want a big block of HTML. I will change it.